# Wordpress site not opening

Tags: wordpress

I bought a domain from GoDaddy and hosting from another company. after completing method I logged in to my Cpanel and installed wordpress successfully.

After that, it give me two links one is for checking my website front end and the second one is for the backend. Now the problem is  I can't access my website nor backend nor frontend both links show me the message

> unexpectedly closed the connection.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: With your provider. This isn't the place for that type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly update domain name server. Hosting provider provide a hosting name server.

So please update name server than try.

Your both url working